# How can I auto-scroll a wxTreeControl widget while dragging with the mouse?

Tags: wxwidgets, scrollbar, treecontrol

I have a wxTreeCtrl widget with scroll bars, where I want to drag and drop items on other items. But when I drag an item, how can I make the control automatically scroll invisible items into view?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you should do it manually. Derive a class from wxTreeCtrl, override relevant methods to capture mouse drag event. Then manually call scroll function with a reasonable amount when the dragging is at the top/bottom.